# Having problems installing python-docx

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, python-docx

```
>>> import docx

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\kevin\mu_code\docx\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>

    from docx.api import Document  # noqa

  File "c:\users\kevin\mu_code\docx\api.py", line 14, in <module>

    from docx.package import Package

  File "c:\users\kevin\mu_code\docx\package.py", line 9, in <module>

    from docx.opc.package import OpcPackage

  File "c:\users\kevin\mu_code\docx\opc\package.py", line 9, in <module>

    from docx.opc.part import PartFactory

  File "c:\users\kevin\mu_code\docx\opc\part.py", line 12, in <module>

    from .oxml import serialize_part_xml

  File "c:\users\kevin\mu_code\docx\opc\oxml.py", line 12, in <module>

    from lxml import etree

ImportError: cannot import name 'etree'
```

I have python-docx 0.8.10 and lxml 4.5.0, windows 10. I tried googling already but I'm not sure if I followed the suggestions correctly or if it's applicable in my case (lxml problems). I haven't had any problems installing other modules using "pip install" so I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

Use pip install, to install the docx library and if you have already install it successfully then have a look into its dependencies. I think it is because of the incompatibility with its dependencies that is why you are getting the error.

```
pip install python-docx

Dependencies
Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, or 3.4
lxml >= 2.3.2
```

I don't know whether this may be an appropriate solution for you. But this is what I generally follow. Just install Anaconda in your system and an environment according to your needs. For your case create an environment for Python 3.4 using the following command

```
conda create --name py34 python=3.4
```

You then install libraries according to your needs in the respective environment. Now you can work into each environment without interfering with the libraries of the other environment. To use anaconda kindly follow Anaconda cheatsheet.

Kindly refer to the [link](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html). Hope this helps you.

Comment: `python-docx==0.8.10

  - lxml [required: >=2.3.2, installed: 4.5.0]
`
This is the result when I check the dependencies.. It's not showing the Python versions. However, I have Python 3.8. Is it not compatible with python-docx?

Comment: Only Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, or 3.4 are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a problem with the `lxml` install. `python-docx` works with all versions of Python >= 2.6.

Instead of `import docx`, try `from lxml import etree`. If this produces the same error message, you know you've narrowed it down.

`lxml` depends on a couple of C libraries, `lib2xml` and `libxslt` if I remember correctly. These are sometimes tricky to install. In any case, you'll find solutions to those problems by searching on "lxml install windows" or similar.

Once `from lxml import etree` works without error I think you'll find `import docx` does too.